# How to push data to firebase without generating new key

Tags: javascript, firebase

Want to push data to firebase without generating a new key.

I tried

```
var userInfo1 = {
    [data.macid]: key1,
};
const ref1 = FirebaseFactory.child('macid');
return ref1.push(userInfo1);
```

It creates a new id for each time. I want to push data without generating a new key. If using set instead of push, it deleted all data and created new data.

Firebase came to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you would like the result to look like

Answer (score 0):

While [storing data in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) realtime/firestore you store data in documents that contain fields mapping to values.
These documents are auto-generated and thus have unique keys associated with them.
If you push data in already generated document, it won't generate new key then.
You  can also create shallow queries to retrieve data at the document level without needing to retrieve the entire collection, or any nested subcollections.